# Can't un-ignore a directory with TortoiseSVN

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I wanted to ignore the 'output' directory, so in the context-menu I chose `tortoiseSVN->unversion and add to ignore list`, which I later realized was not what I wanted, since I wanted that directory to continue to exist in the repository.

I've looked at the Ignore property in the parent directory, and 'output' is not there, and recreating it and doing a 'commit' doesn't make it show up either.

I even tried to make a placeholder file inside the directory and committing that, but TortoiseSVN barfs with a 'path not found' error.

Comment: Check output dir. And changes introduced in commit, which reflect "unversion and add to ignore list": if it was single action in commit (must be so in good hands), you can just rollback commit

Comment: When you invoke the `unversion and add to ignore list` this should set `svn:ignore` on the parent directory. I just tested it on my system and that is indeed what happened. So you might want to first address the question of where is svn:ignore getting set, if at all, when you do the initial command, and that might then give a clue as to why the second part fails.

Comment: no idea why svn:ignore wasn't being set, but I just reverted the commit, and I've figured out that you can't ignore versioned files, so I'll just have to live with it.

Answer (score 5):

Right click in the directory where your ignored file or folder is and select properties svn:ignore with values which is inclusive or just your ignored list. either edit or delete(if it has just your list) that property.

and/or simply you can right click and select check for modifications and select the ignored files/folder and select revert

Hope this helps

Comment: Revert can revert some changes that you did before Ignoring. +1 for the help still.